# Python async SQL ORM with custom SQL lazy querysets

Tags: python, sql, asynchronous, tortoise-orm, ormar

I generally use Python ORMs like Tortoise ORM or Ormar ORM (because they're async, integrate well with FastAPI, have very good performances (for Tortoise ORM), can use single Pydantic/type-hinted models (for Ormar). And of course also from habit.)

However, I have now a use case it seems I cannot do with Tortoise ORM neither Ormar ORM:
I would like to do lazily apply custom SQL queries on existing querysets (by lazily, I mean the two consecutive queries need to be executed only once, later).

e.g. current simplified Tortoise ORM lazy query logic:

```
async def main() -> list:
    await connect_db()
    query_1 = Users.all().only("id", "name", "age")
    query_2 = query_1.order_by("-age")
    return await query_2
```

I would need to apply one query (say `query_3`) but with custom SQL, so I would have something like that:

```
async def main() -> list:
    await connect_db()
    query_1 = Users.all().only("id", "name", "age")
    query_2 = query_1.order_by("-age")
    query_3 = query_2.custom_query("SELECT id, name, age FROM users WHERE age > 18;")
    return await query_3
```

Can I do something like that with an ORM? Which one and how? Thanks!